# Creating array of objects with fixed size in Kotlin

Tags: android, arrays, kotlin

How I can create Array of my custom objects with fixed size in Kotlin?

like?

```
ArrayList<CustomObject> array = new ArrayList<>()
```

or ?

```
CustomObject[] objects = new CustomObjects[5]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two options:

- [`arrayOfNulls(size: Int)`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/array-of-nulls.html) - creates an array of a specific size and populates it will null references. It's not possible to use this function with non-nullable types.
- [`<init>(size: Int, init: (Int) -> T)`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-array/-init-.html) constructor - creates an array of a specific size and runs supplied lambda for every index in the array to create an element for that index.

Comment: private val customObjectArray = arrayOfNulls<customObject>(5)

customObjectArray[0] = CustomObject(this, 2)